# Sylius 1.0.0dev- base currency is thrown out when adding new currency

Tags: sylius

I added new currency EUR. The symfony debug toolbar now shows the base currency as "undefined" (in green colour as the selected value) and shows USD next to it (grey colour). 
Also there is twig runtime error (currency could not be found) when rendering layout.html.twig and this is obvious as it arrives from renderSelectorAction in currency controller.

I think something is broken.
Can someone explain how to set up new currencies in Sylius 1 dev.
Thanks

Comment: Which currency is set as the Default Currency for your channel? And make sure your parameters.yml file's currency value matches one of the values specified in the Channel settings

Comment: Thanks. Both default currency and parameters.yml remained exactly as per default config. The steps i took where: 1) create new locale, 2) create new currency, 3) create new channel. I am not sure at exactly which point the base currency was removed

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by just selecting the base channel from debug toolbar. It removed the undefined currency and selected US$.